# Sort row data into columns with same heading in excel 2010

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, excel-2010

Put simply, I need to sort row data for a specific range into the correct columns based on that columns heading. For example, if there are five columns labelled A through E, and data in the rows below ranging from A through E; I need all of the A's to be in the A column, all of the B's in the B column etc.
Example start data:

[image: example]

How it should look after the sort:

[image: desired result]

It also must be able to work with the possibility of having empty cells. For example; if the first example data had no B in row 3, the data must not shift over to the left so that C is in the B column etc.

Other info: not feasible to do by hand - over 450 rows.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Have you tried any code? You might want to try it and post the code so that we can take it from there?

Comment: I haven't used any code

Comment: Btw the above can be achieve with a simple COUNTIF formula as well.

Comment: Would you be interested in an Excel formula?

Comment: If it can do the job then yeah of course

Comment: Ok one moment.. posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It also must be able to work with the possibility of having empty cells.

Taking the above into consideration.

**NON VBA WAY**

Insert enough columns so that the data moves to the right

[image]

Next in the row one, duplicate the values from your data

[image]

Next in Cell `A2` Put this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF($H$2:$L$2,A1)>0,A1,"")
```

[image]

Copy the formula to the right

[image]

Next remove "$" from the table range and add it to the header in formula in Cell `A2` so that we can copy the formula down. This is how it would look

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H2:L2,$A$1)>0,$A$1,"")
```

Similarly your `B2` formula will look like this

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H2:L2,$B$1)>0,$B$1,"")
```

Change it for the rest

[image]

How highlight cells `A2:E2` and copy the formula down.

[image]

Your final `Sorted` Data looks like this.

[image]

Copy columns `A:E` and do a paste special values on Col `A:E` itself so that the formulas change into values and then delete `Cols H:L`